# Algoritmo para transitar no plano cartesiano

Tags: java, algoritmo

Estou tentando codar a solução para o problema clássico de passear pelo plano cartesiano, partindo da origem, com base em uma String de entrada dada pelo usuário.
Sendo:

- *E*: rotação anti-horária de 90°;
- *D*: rotação horária de 90°;
- *F*: desloca uma posição para frente;
- *T*: desloca uma posição para trás;

A direção e sentido iniciais são, respectivamente, leste e direita.

A saída para a String `DFD` é `(-1,0)` por exemplo.

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String entrada = sc.nextLine();
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        int tamEntrada = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i <entrada.length(); i++) {
            if(entrada.charAt(i)=='D') {
                if(x!=0) {
                    int aux = y;
                    y=-x;
                    x=-aux;
                }
                else {
                    int aux=y;
                    y=x;
                    y=aux;
                    
                }   
            }
            else if(entrada.charAt(i)=='E') {
                if(x!=0) {
                    int aux=y;
                    y=x;
                    y=aux;
                    
                }
                else {
                    x=-y;
                    y=0;
                }   
            }
            else if(entrada.charAt(i)=='F') 
                x++;
            else if(entrada.charAt(i)=='T') 
                y--;
                
            
        }       
                
        
        System.out.println("(" + x +"," + y +")");
 
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

Ele funciona com rotações em torno da origem, mas não com rotações da origem. Não consigo visualizar uma possível correção. Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inicialmente eu havia entendido que a rotação é apenas uma mudança de direção, sem sair do lugar. Mas também há a possibilidade de rotacionar em relação à origem, mudando a posição. Seguem abaixo soluções para ambos os casos.

---

### Rotação sem sair do lugar

Se a ideia da rotação é somente mudar a direção, não precisa ficar trocando os valores de `x` e `y`. Em vez disso, você poderia ter uma variável para controlar a direção atual e mudá-la ao encontrar um "D" ou "E", e para avançar ou retroceder uma posição, você simplesmente altera os valores de `x` ou `y` de acordo com a direção:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String entrada = sc.nextLine();
int x = 0, y = 0;
int direcao = 0; // 0 - norte, 1 - leste, 2 - sul, 3 - oeste
for (int i = 0; i < entrada.length(); i++) {
    char c = entrada.charAt(i);
    switch (c) {
        case 'D':
            direcao = (direcao + 1) % 4;
            break;
        case 'E':
            direcao = (direcao + 3) % 4;
            break;
        case 'F':
        case 'T': // para frente ou para trás, a lógica é a mesma
            int passo = 1;
            if (c == 'T') { // se for para trás, o passo é negativo
                passo = -1;
            }
            switch (direcao) {
                case 0: // norte, muda só y
                    y += passo;
                    break;
                case 1: // leste, muda só x
                    x += passo;
                    break;
                case 2: // sul, muda só y
                    y -= passo;
                    break;
                case 3: // oeste, muda só x
                    x -= passo;
                    break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            // opção inválida, não faz nada (ou pode colocar alguma mensagem de erro, ou lançar exceção, etc)
    }
}

System.out.printf("(%d, %d)\n", x, y);
```

Repare que ao encontrar "D" ou "E", eu só mudo de direção, sem fazer "malabarismos" com os valores de `x` e `y`. Eu só mudo os valores destes quando for para andar (verificando a direção atual e se devo andar para frente ou para trás).

As direções eu considerei como os "pontos cardeais", então "norte" seria para avançar no eixo y, "leste" para avançar no eixo x, "sul" para retroceder no eixo y e "oeste" para retroceder no eixo x:

```
        norte
          |
          |
oeste ----|---- leste
          |
          |
         sul
```

Para isso eu usei o operador `%`, que retorna o resto da divisão. Ou seja, se a direção atual é 3 (oeste), para rodar no sentido horário eu somo 1 e pego o resto da divisão por 4, que resulta em zero (norte). Então se rodar várias vezes, eu terei as direções 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3 e assim por diante.

Já para rodar no sentido anti-horário, eu avanço 3 posições (assim eu mudo de zero para 3, ou seja, de norte para oeste, e depois para sul, leste, norte, oeste, etc). Eu somei 3 vez de subtrair 1 porque para valores negativos daria errado (se eu começo do zero, eu teria `-1 % 4`, que resulta em `-1`, que seria uma direção inválida).

Eu também uso [`printf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) para formatar a posição, em vez de concatenar strings (é apenas para mostrar outra forma de fazer).

Por fim, não precisa fechar o `System.in` (como regra geral, devemos fechar todo recurso que abrimos, mas o `System.in` é exceção - leia mais sobre isso [aqui](/a/380458/112052) e [aqui](/a/380696/112052)).

---

Como já dito no início, eu fiz "F" ser "para frente" e "T" ser "para trás" (o contrário do que está na pergunta), então o resultado do código acima para "DFD" é `(1, 0)`. Mas se a ideia é ser ao contrário ("F" ser "para trás"), basta trocar o `if` acima para:

```
if (c == 'F') { // "F" é "para trás"
    passo = -1;
}
```

---

Outra alternativa é ter um array com os passos:

```
int x = 0, y = 0;
int direcao = 0; // 0 - norte, 1 - leste, 2 - sul, 3 - oeste
int[][] passos = { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 0 }, { 0, -1 }, { -1, 0 } };
for (int i = 0; i < entrada.length(); i++) {
    char c = entrada.charAt(i);
    switch (c) {
        case 'D':
            direcao = (direcao + 1) % 4;
            break;
        case 'E':
            direcao = (direcao + 3) % 4;
            break;
        case 'F':
            x += passos[direcao][0];
            y += passos[direcao][1];
            break;
        case 'T':
            x -= passos[direcao][0];
            y -= passos[direcao][1];
            break;
        default:
            // opção inválida, não faz nada (ou pode colocar alguma mensagem de erro, ou lançar exceção, etc)
    }
}
```

Assim, a direção também serve como índice do array `passos`, então `passos[direcao]` retorna outro array contendo o incremento a ser feito tanto em `x` quanto em `y`.

No exemplo acima eu fiz "F" ser "para a frente", mas se quiser, basta inverter "F" e "T" no código caso queira que "F" seja "para trás".

---

Por fim, outra alternativa (agradecimentos ao [Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/70/bacco) pelo algoritmo) é ter duas variáveis para os passos no eixo x e y, e ir mudando os seus valores de acordo com a direção:

```
int x = 0, y = 0;
int dx = 0, dy = -1;
int s;
for (int i = 0; i < entrada.length(); i++) {
    switch (entrada.charAt(i)) {
        case 'E':
            s = dx;
            dx = -dy;
            dy = s;
            break;
        case 'D':
            s = dx;
            dx = dy;
            dy = -s;
            break;
        case 'F':
            x += dx;
            y += dy;
            break;
        case 'T':
            x -= dx;
            y -= dy;
            break;
    }
}
```

---

### Rotação em relação à origem

Agora, se a ideia de rotacionar é mudar a posição em relação à origem, basta adicionar a mudança de posição no caso acima:

```
int x = 0, y = 0, aux;
int direcao = 1; // 0 - norte, 1 - leste, 2 - sul, 3 - oeste
for (int i = 0; i < entrada.length(); i++) {
    char c = entrada.charAt(i);
    switch (c) {
        case 'D':
            direcao = (direcao + 1) % 4;
            // rotaciona 90 graus no sentido horário
            aux = x;
            x = y;
            y = -aux;
            break;
        case 'E':
            direcao = (direcao + 3) % 4;
            // rotaciona 90 graus no sentido anti-horário
            aux = x;
            x = -y;
            y = x;
            break;
        case 'F':
        case 'T': // para frente ou para trás, a lógica é a mesma
            int passo = 1;
            if (c == 'T') { // se for para trás, o passo é negativo
                passo = -1;
            }
            switch (direcao) {
                case 0: // norte, muda só y
                    y += passo;
                    break;
                case 1: // leste, muda só x
                    x += passo;
                    break;
                case 2: // sul, muda só y
                    y -= passo;
                    break;
                case 3: // oeste, muda só x
                    x -= passo;
                    break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            // opção inválida, não faz nada (ou pode colocar alguma mensagem de erro, ou lançar exceção, etc)
    }
}
```

Comment: Realmente genial essa ideia de "tatuar" as direções com valores e trabalhar com os restos. Só vou modificar "direção" para 1 apontando assim, inicialmente, para leste (acredito que esteja em norte).

Comment: @gmn_1450 Atualizei a resposta com mais algumas opções - mas todas seguem a mesma ideia: a mudança de direção atualiza o "passo", e o movimento atualiza x e y de acordo com o passo definido pela direção atual

Comment: Muito obrigado. Já consigo visualizar possíveis variações dessa solução. :)

Comment: A saída para FFFDT não deveria ser (0,-2)?
(Assumindo que eu parta do leste)...claro.

Comment: @gmn_1450 Vc considerou que "F" é pra frente ou pra trás? De qualquer forma, se você começa na direção leste, FFF deveria andar 3 posições no eixo X, depois D deveria virar para o sul e T deveria andar somente no eixo Y. Então se F é "pra frente", vc termina em (3, 1) e se F for "pra trás", vc terminaria em (-3, -1)

Comment: Alterei à pergunta para considerar "F" como "frente" e "direcao" para 1, já que a posição inicial é à direita no leste. . Apesar disso, ainda não acho que tenha entendido. A saída para á entrada FFFDT, por exemplo, deveria ser (0,-2) devido aos três passos iniciais no eixo x (leste), seguidos de uma rotação horária, que levaria à coordenada para (0,-3) e, por fim, de um passo para trás; chegando a (0,-2).

Comment: @gmn_1450 Ah, o código que eu fiz considera que a rotação é simplesmente "rodar sem sair do lugar", ou seja, eu só mudo a direção, sem mudar a posição. Então a solução é um pouco diferente, atualizo a resposta em breve

Comment: @gmn_1450 Resposta atualizada, deixei as 2 opções (rotacionar sem sair do lugar e em relação à origem), assim a resposta fica mais completa :-)

Comment: Obrigado por revisitar e, sobretudo, atualizar o código. Peço desculpas pela imprecisão da minha pergunta. A atualizarei. :)